# Unable to display data in a tabcontrol page

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mysql-workbench, tabcontrol

I have a mysql database linked to a tab control with multiple tables in visual studio. The Authors data will load into the first tabcontrol form. However, I am experiencing an issue where I cannot get the Books data to be displayed in another tab control form.

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using MySql;
using System.Configuration;
using MySql.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Globalization;

 namespace mydatabase
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }       

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.IsMdiContainer = true;
        string constring ="atasource=localhost;Port=3306;database
        =mydatabase;username=root;password=mypassword;persist
        security info=True"; 

        MySqlConnection MySqlConn = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("select * from   mydatabase.Authors;", MySqlConn);

        try
        {

        MySqlDataAdapter daAuthors = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        daAuthors.SelectCommand = command;
        DataTable dtAuthors = new DataTable();
        DataSet dsAuthors = new DataSet();
        daAuthors.Fill(dtAuthors);
        dsAuthors.Tables.Add(dtAuthors);

        dtAuthors.Columns["AuthorID"].AutoIncrement = true;
        dtAuthors.Columns[0].AutoIncrementStep = 1;

            // Bind the DataTable to the UI via a BindingSource.

        BindingSource AuthorBindingSource = new BindingSource();

        AuthorBindingSource.DataSource = dtAuthors;                       AuthorBindingNavigator.BindingSource = AuthorBindingSource;
       txtAuthorID.DataBindings.Add("Text", AuthorBindingSource, "AuthorID");
       txtAuthorCode.DataBindings.Add("Text", AuthorBindingSource, "AuthorCode");
       txtAuthorName.DataBindings.Add("Text", AuthorBindingSource, "AuthorName");


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.GetType().ToString());


            string conBook = "datasource=localhost;Port=3306;database=mydatabase;userid=root;password=mypassword;persist security info=True";
            MySqlConnection mySqlConnBook = new MySqlConnection(conBook);
            MySqlCommand cmdBook = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * From mydatabase.Book", mySqlConnBook);

         MySqlDataAdapter daBook = new MySqlDataAdapter();
         daBook.SelectCommand = cmdBook;
         DataTable dtBook = new DataTable();
         DataSet dsBook = new DataSet();

        dtBook.Columns["BookCodeID"].AutoIncrement = true;
        dtBook.Columns[0].AutoIncrementStep = 1;

        // Bind the DataTable to the UI via a BindingSource.
        BindingSource BookBindingSource = new BindingSource();

       BookBindingSource.DataSource = dtBook;
       BookBindingNavigator.BindingSource = BookBindingSource;

       txtBookCodeID.DataBindings.Add("Text", BookBindingSource, "BookCodeID");
       txtBookDescription.DataBindings.Add("Text", BookBindingSource, "BookDescription");
        }
    }

}
```

}

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your books data displaying logic is in the catch block, which means it will be run only if there is an exception when loading the Addresses.Take it out of the catch block.

Comment: Another suggestion will be to break up your code as below..try
{
LoadAuthors(constring);
LoadBooks(constring);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
 MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}

Comment: @ skimad: thank you for your response and it solve my problem. I took the authors and books data displaying logic and separate these code segments into blocks by enclosing them each In region segments:  #region and #endregion: e.g. #region Load Authors() #endregion and #region Load Books() #endregion. I cannot find the "answered" button to click and show that you answered and provided a solution to my issue. Thanks again.